# undefined index error in php for image upload in mysql db

Tags: php

i m trying to upload image in a mysql table but am getting this error " Undefined index: image " I know there are similar questions but couldn't find a solution.

#### HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### PHP

```php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_POST['image']['tmp_name'])); 
$image_name = addslashes($_POST['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO paper1 (img) VALUES ('{$image}')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}
```

Comment: When you add a question, underneath where you type is a preview of how it will be displayed on the site. Make sure you check that because your code had a couple of very simple errors that caused the HTML and PHP parts not to show up at all.

Comment: @PeteR oh really? It gives me _Site not found_

Comment: Mix of SQL functions amongst other things. Try to fill up your Ferrari with Diesel fuel, see what gives. Here `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))` that ought to "fire" it up. And this `('{$image}')` could be `('$image')` and `$image_name = addslashes($_POST['image']['name']);` to `$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);` and the other `$_POST` too. @user3376161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the other issues that have already been outlined, you're mixing SQL functions plus your `$_POST` should be `$_FILES` and the braces in `('{$image}')` should be removed.

You're presently connecting with a `mysqli_*` based function `$con = mysqli_connect...` but executing the query with a `mysql_*` based  functions; they do not mix.

```
if (!mysql_query($sql))
```

---

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); 
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO paper1 (img) VALUES ('$image')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}
```

I'm just not sure what you wish to do with `$image_name` since there is no other reference to that variable.

Comment: hey guys thanks, somehow it worked, wasnt expecting response so quickly, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out for you, always a pleasure to help out. @user3376161 if you feel this answer helped to resolve the issue, do click the accept checkmark to close the question. There's a little white checkmark, click it till it turns green ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$_FILES['image']` instead of `$_POST['image']`.

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); 
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

`<input type="file"/>` do not end up in the `$_POST` variable but in the `$_FILES` variable.

You get the error `undefined index` because there is no index with the name `image` in your array `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form tag

```
 <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And in php, Use `$_FILES` instead of  `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the file input name is not "image" and your code wants it.

Comment: Not $_POST, but $_FILES